# Do all Ubuntu flavors share same software sources?

Tags: software-center, desktop-environments, versions

Ubuntu has several recognized favors namely Studio, Xubuntu, Lubuntu and many more ([Ubuntu flavors and derivatives](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DerivativeTeam/Derivatives)).

The question is :

- When using software center, do users find the same applications on all recognized flavors ?
- Does the applications (and their versions) available  to the different flavors **change** due to desktop environment or other dependencies ?
- Specifically, I also, want to know whether the different flavors
  share the same version of an application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all Ubuntu flavors share the same repository.

You can install any application to any flavor, but if some application requires some DE specific libraries, they will be installed too.

For example, if you install `k3b` to a non-kde system, apt will pull a lot of KDE related packages.

Versions of applications do not depend on a flavor.